# TypeError: Argument 3 of SubtleCrypto.wrapKey does not implement interface CryptoKey

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 and would like to implement [js-jose](https://github.com/square/js-jose/tree/master/dist). It has a `jose.min.js` file.

**Question**

Within the Ionic2 structure, how do I import the [js-jose](https://github.com/square/js-jose/tree/master/dist) library?

**UPDATE**

This is what I did. It builds with no errors, however, when I run the `encrypt` function, it does not enter the `Promise`.

The following is printed:

> `encryptPerson: Object { id=8,  joiningDate=1472815177067,  lastAccessDate=1475158964295,  more...}`
>   `encrypt: password1`

But I would also expect it to print the following, but it does not.

> `encryptPerson: resolve  <PersonModel>`

There error I get is:

**ERROR**

> `TypeError: Argument 3 of SubtleCrypto.wrapKey does not implement interface CryptoKey.`

**Install**

> `npm install https://github.com/square/js-jose.git --save`

**code**

```
import * as jose from "jose-jwe-jws";

    private cryptographer: any = null;
    private rsa_key: any = null;
    private encrypter: any = null;

    constructor( @Inject(Http) http: Http) {
        super();
        this.http = http;
        this.initEncryption();
    }

private encryptPerson(person: PersonModel): Promise<PersonModel> {
    console.log('encryptPerson: ', person);
    return new Promise<PersonModel>(resolve => {
        let password: string = person.password;
        this.encrypt(password).then((ciphertext: string) => {
            person.password = ciphertext;
            console.log('encryptPerson: resolve ', person);
            resolve(person);
        });
    });
}

private encrypt(value: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log('encrypt: ', value);
    return this.encrypter.encrypt(value);
}

    private initEncryption(): void {
        this.cryptographer = new jose.Jose.WebCryptographer();
        this.rsa_key = {
            // n = modulus
            "n": "00:c2:4b:af:0f:2d:2b:ad:36:72:a7:91:0f:ee:30:a0:95:d5:3a:46:82:86:96:7e:42:c6:fe:8f:20:97:af:49:f6:48:a3:91:53:ac:2e:e6:ec:9a:9a:e0:0a:fb:1c:db:44:40:5b:8c:fc:d5:1c:cb:b6:9b:60:c0:a8:ac:06:f1:6b:29:5e:2f:7b:09:d9:93:32:da:3f:db:53:9c:2e:ea:3b:41:7f:6b:c9:7b:88:9f:2e:c5:dd:42:1e:7f:8f:04:f6:60:3c:fe:43:6d:32:10:ce:8d:99:cb:76:f7:10:97:05:af:28:1e:39:0f:78:35:50:7b:8e:28:22:a4:7d:11:51:22:d1:0e:ab:6b:6f:96:cb:cf:7d:eb:c6:aa:a2:6a:2e:97:2a:93:af:a5:89:e6:c8:bc:9f:fd:85:2b:0f:b4:c0:e4:ca:b5:a7:9a:01:05:81:93:6b:f5:8d:1c:f7:f3:77:0e:6e:53:34:92:0f:48:21:34:33:44:14:5e:4a:00:41:3a:7d:cb:38:82:c1:65:e0:79:ea:a1:05:84:b2:6e:40:19:77:1a:0e:38:4b:28:1f:34:b5:cb:ac:c5:2f:58:51:d7:ec:a8:08:0e:7c:c0:20:c1:5e:a1:4d:b1:30:17:63:0e:e7:58:8e:7f:6e:9f:a4:77:8b:1e:a2:d2:2e:1b:e9",

            // e = publicExponent
            "e": 65537,

            // d = privateExponent
            "d": "37:b6:4b:f4:26:17:a8:0b:3c:c5:1f:ab:59:b9:47:d2:ae:d9:8e:ee:4e:79:48:ab:0d:34:61:06:0f:78:8b:d4:ba:ef:6b:f4:7a:22:d8:c4:6f:70:89:5d:9c:b3:a1:8b:e8:88:57:dd:07:9e:c2:2b:12:52:a3:eb:b9:a8:24:01:7e:53:2b:7a:34:50:d7:0c:75:d8:69:a3:87:dd:4b:fc:c1:c3:2f:bd:0e:57:16:8d:ea:de:8e:de:ff:e4:9a:9f:aa:e8:d2:5f:b3:27:ef:f9:ca:50:97:2e:fd:99:1c:34:dd:0c:bb:dd:d0:b9:bf:4f:dc:9d:de:94:50:66:2c:58:7e:c2:31:8b:41:56:49:6a:e6:11:14:53:a1:45:0d:15:8b:26:79:0f:c9:dc:ac:dc:c7:bc:55:2c:96:ed:a7:29:09:04:ee:00:74:60:e1:bc:97:7b:0a:b6:f2:83:82:79:65:e0:aa:88:9f:90:b0:0d:76:4d:3c:08:7e:a5:05:19:d4:8b:54:d3:f1:c1:a3:e3:a5:1e:aa:d6:c4:94:ad:6c:b3:8f:85:06:8a:6f:52:f8:a3:c3:e0:8d:67:35:2f:d4:18:fc:70:f4:71:bf:18:88:d6:a7:b7:04:8e:d3:06:ca:83:c3:2d:21:98:65:c9:41:2c:77:bf:4c:7c:8c:2c:01",

            // p = prime1
            "p": "00:fa:d6:06:46:5c:04:70:e6:ec:47:02:96:02:a5:e2:41:9d:bd:7b:97:28:a4:c5:3b:b5:9b:0a:6b:7d:b6:44:8a:28:1e:d1:ef:cb:44:ef:eb:4d:08:74:80:f5:cf:3b:b7:40:10:60:c9:18:1e:a5:76:4b:41:37:06:b2:71:03:60:25:77:db:d0:b2:21:dc:b0:32:90:a2:10:9a:d5:e6:e3:11:42:a1:9a:7a:26:3c:d3:12:56:db:25:07:69:be:ae:2c:b9:33:6c:29:e3:65:b9:5b:05:84:05:e6:da:c4:f4:3f:ab:84:60:6e:f0:5f:ba:a8:98:8f:72:2c:c8:40:d1",

            // q = prime2
            "q": "00:c6:4b:ac:fe:40:1c:dc:6c:78:07:cc:3e:db:4e:d5:d0:17:3b:8f:04:f0:ae:c4:22:0d:8b:0a:4d:0f:9e:fe:c7:e6:38:b5:53:ba:a9:e8:f0:47:28:14:25:95:6a:79:ab:db:86:97:82:c5:1e:bd:80:a5:aa:a2:b7:a5:c7:48:17:c4:d9:c7:4f:50:2a:69:67:15:4c:0b:f5:e6:fb:20:23:5d:ea:ae:6c:c6:74:ba:cc:f8:06:2b:41:1f:b6:3f:2a:93:fa:f9:e1:ee:93:c3:92:ad:49:c7:8f:db:72:ff:6b:f0:f0:d6:2f:83:ce:1c:82:16:89:57:01:9f:49:2f:99",

            // dp = exponent1
            "dp": "57:d4:c1:75:b9:9a:c4:7d:d7:96:35:cd:99:37:c4:b5:fd:29:f0:30:c9:c6:88:59:94:09:a9:e8:61:a8:84:ef:6b:84:ff:35:dc:13:53:7f:2d:06:1c:e5:5b:2d:29:57:cd:52:ee:d0:fb:65:1f:c3:00:2e:e1:b9:b2:99:e7:f8:ae:a5:fd:8e:62:11:81:59:21:1b:8b:e4:0c:93:81:b9:58:bd:e0:20:5b:4d:30:57:28:40:c9:93:79:b9:09:4f:ab:d1:5d:b4:2e:26:b5:e3:e5:7f:54:ef:4c:1a:a6:84:70:16:fa:cf:59:89:49:bb:ee:75:1d:25:79:90:d5:41",

            // dq = exponent2
            "dq": "00:ab:eb:a8:8c:b7:21:4e:aa:6c:56:b6:6a:38:d1:dc:e6:91:7d:fd:bd:96:be:af:25:a7:00:49:6a:0e:85:16:f8:51:4e:11:48:0a:aa:8d:5e:e5:12:86:85:1f:4a:35:3b:1f:15:4d:fe:fe:d0:6c:14:41:8d:f3:8d:ad:99:5d:93:de:03:c2:9d:ad:2f:58:3b:1b:67:d7:66:d7:60:1a:b9:0f:10:0d:32:19:cd:d2:b7:2a:c2:8e:75:e3:fc:aa:3f:4c:15:68:d8:cd:74:27:37:e0:2d:fb:6b:6a:24:05:f7:9b:e9:f2:89:37:89:57:86:21:eb:e9:17:6a:f6:94:e1",

            // qi = coefficient
            "qi": "0a:ed:5f:30:67:d5:e5:6e:4a:7a:35:49:fe:16:2f:1e:91:2b:39:c3:01:d3:d4:c0:4d:b3:fc:08:b0:66:e9:44:10:9e:5b:5a:ea:83:a5:9c:95:7a:58:70:35:28:e5:4d:ba:19:de:0d:66:f9:db:5c:f6:5b:24:27:9d:0b:2d:44:40:eb:33:3a:19:e2:1d:c0:b0:16:99:d1:c1:52:84:02:d6:67:06:32:f8:4d:cb:42:9f:7c:8a:e0:ad:df:40:6f:e4:8c:f6:f6:9e:1d:bd:43:e3:38:91:a2:d0:9e:60:ff:9d:8c:fb:72:5b:df:95:30:17:d2:f2:cb:7d:92:56:0a"
        };
        this.encrypter = new jose.JoseJWE.Encrypter(this.cryptographer, this.rsa_key);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running the following:

```
npm install node-jose
```

UPDATE:

You can add a catch block and get the error message in a case of a failure - you can find an example for the catch block here: github.com/square/js-jose

Comment: Hi @galvan, thanks for the reply.  I did try: `npm install https://github.com/square/js-jose.git --save`. This seems to work, however I still have a problem that the encryption is not working.  I have updated my explanation above.

Comment: Can you also add catch block and see if you get any error message - you can find an example for the catch block here: https://github.com/square/js-jose

Comment: Thanks, the catch showed I am getting the following error. Now just to work out how to fix it.  `TypeError: Argument 3 of SubtleCrypto.wrapKey does not implement interface CryptoKey.`

Comment: I've just edited the previous answer, will appreciate if you can mark it as resolved

Comment: I cannot mark this as the answer because it helped provide more information. But it did not resolve the problem, It would be nice if people could still look at this. I have given it a +1 though.