# Encryption with Ionic 2

Tags: encryption, ionic2

I am looking to implement Encrypt/Decrypt functionality in my Ionic 2 app.  I am looking for something simple, that will work with Ionic 2.

Please can anyone recommend a library/plugin that works with Ionic 2?

I have tried a few libraries, but cannot get them to work in Ionic 2. I have issues with the import into Ionic 2.

E.g.

Using [js-jose](https://github.com/square/js-jose), I get the following error:

[TypeError: Argument 3 of SubtleCrypto.wrapKey does not implement interface CryptoKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479559/typeerror-argument-3-of-subtlecrypto-wrapkey-does-not-implement-interface-crypt/40482177?noredirect=1#comment68210452_40482177)

Using [Crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js), I get the following error:

[JavaScript library of crypto standards implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467395/javascript-library-of-crypto-standards-implementation)

Comment: What version of Ionic 2 are you using?

Comment: I wrote a tutorial called, Build a Password Manager for Android and iOS Using Ionic 2, which might help. https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/07/build-a-password-manager-for-android-and-ios-using-ionic-2/

Answer (score 2):

For storing data on the device, you can switch to secure storage cordova plugin instead of the insecure localstorage. Note For android, you need to have either setup pin or swipe screen lock to make this work.

ionic add plugin cordova-plugin-secure-storage

[cordova-plugin-secure-storage](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage)

**Dont forget to wrap the plugin inside platform.ready()**

```
constructor(public platform: Platform) {


       platform.ready().then(() => {

           this.secureStorage = new SecureStorage();

           this.secureStorage.create('demoAppStorage').then(
               () => {
                   console.log('SecureStorage is ready!');

               },
               error => console.log(error)
           );

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using NodeJS crypto library. https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto

Answer (score 0):

I use [CryptoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) and [CryptoBrowserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-browserify)
i.e

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'; 

import CryptoBrowserify from 'crypto-browserify';

var encrypted = CryptoBrowserify.publicEncrypt( publicKey,new Buffer(data));
```

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for an encryption mechanism in ionic2. Could you please explain it further